# UILabel overlapping UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

IB through the cell `UITableViewCell` added `UISWitch`. When programmatically setting text `UILabel`, `UISwitch` overlaps.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: post you code , how you are doing this.

Comment: Please post your code in order to rectify your problem.

Comment: After sending the message [cell.textLabel setText: cellText]; there is an overlapping UISwitch added through IB.

Comment: Keep constraint with label trailing and switch and numberoflines to 0

Answer (score 1):

add constraint,
that shows distance between them is greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

Get size of text in UILabel and then move UISwitch to new position.

Comment: Sorry, did not have true. I had a mind which is a property textLaibel UITableViewCell. Ie it was not originally added through IB. SizeWithFont:ForWidth: не помогло.

Comment: SizeWithFont:ForWidth: did not help

Comment: Try to just move UISwitch always at the right side of the cell. That way, all switches will be in one "column" and then set maximal width for your label.

Answer (score 0):

If you're placing the switch to the right of your `UILabel`, you can just set it as the accessory view of the cell in your code:

```swift
let switch = UISwitch()
// Position the switch to the trailing edge of the cell
cell.accessoryView = switch 
// Tell the text label to reduce text size if the switch gets in the way
cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

This way, you won't have to deal with positioning / auto layout. I believe this is possible to do in Interface Builder as well -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45849911/1646862 (in that case, make sure you set the *Autoshrink* property of the label)