# iOS UITableViewCell with custom accessoryView in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interface-builder

I'm creating a settings page for my Swift app and (following examples here on SO) I've subclassed a `UITableViewCell` and in the `init()` handlers I've set the `accessoryView` to be a `UISwitch()`.

I also have a custom `@IBInspectable` property on the subclass which is also marked `@IBDesignable`:

```
@IBDesignable class TableViewSwitchCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBInspectable var settingsKey: String?

    func build()
    {
        accessoryView = UISwitch()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        build()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        build()
    }

    // code omitted that uses the settingsKey with NSUserDefaults
}
```

How can I arrange for the `UISwitch` to also be visible in InterfaceBuilder so that I can attach additional targets to it whilst still just subclassing from `UITableViewCell`

Ideally I don't want to create a whole new nib with its own layout, since I still want to retain most of the other features of a standard `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: In IB, is the cell's class set to `UITableViewCell` or `TableViewSwitchCell`?

Comment: @Mark it's set to my sub class

Comment: @Mark also, if it's relevant, my "Designables" status is stuck on "updating", as in this other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216670

Answer (score 4):

Drop `UISwitch` in Interface Builder inside of cell. Then wire it with up `accessoryView` of your cell. On standard basic cells the control tends to be locked in the middle of cell in IB. However in runtime it will be properly positioned.